# Definir valor DEFAULT com String vazia e não como NULL no SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Criei uma tabela no `sqlite` determinando colunas com valor `DEFAULT`. A coluna de exemplo é "nome_fantasia" e nela informei que seria `DEFAULT ''` (String vazia). Ao tentar inserir um dado nessa tabela e não informar valor para essa coluna, o `sqlite` está setando `NULL`. É possível que o campo não possua valor nulo?

**Criação da tabela**

```sql
create table if not exists empresa(
    empresa_id integer not null default 0,          -- ID da empresa
    razao_social varchar(150) not null default '',  -- Razão social
    nome_fantasia varchar(150) not null default '', -- Nome fantasia
    primary key (empresa_id)
);
```

**Comando para inserir o registro**

```sql
INSERT into empresa (razao_social) VALUES ("Empresa Teste");
```

**Comando para visualizar o resultado após a inserção**

```sql
SELECT * FROM empresa;
```

**Resulta do obtido pelo select**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realizei testes utilizando como cliente o [Navcat](https://www.navicat.com/en/) na versão 10.0.3. Também tentei fazer o `insert` diretamente no CLI `sqlite3` e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Uma observação que notei é que se existe algum valor dentro das aspas ao declarar o `DEFAULT` da coluna ele é setado corretamente, como por exemplo `DEFAULT ' '` (tem um espaço vazio entre as aspas) ou `DEFAULT 'VALOR DEFAULT'`. A situação ocorre somente para `''` (sem espaço entre as aspas) e `NULL` onde parecem ser entendidos como sendo a mesma coisa e se comparado ao `MySql` existe a diferença. Sei que o SQLite tem suas particularidades, só queria entender se é possível deixar a coluna com a string vazia e não sendo `NULL`.

Comment: Não consegui simular essa situação, o default deveria funcionar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e0afd/1

Comment: Com a sua confirmação que esta funcionando corretamente, procurei outros clients para analisar a situação e realmente está tudo funcionando normalmente. O que mostra que apenas no meu Client que está mostrando a informação de modo errado.

Answer (score 1):

Após realizar muitas pesquisas depois do comentário do **Daniel Mendes**, resolvi instalar diversos clients para visualização do meu `database`, e no comparativo o problema na verdade é do Navcat. Ele exibe o dado incorretamente. Toda a estrutura que o `Sqlite` montou está funcionando corretamente sem nenhum problema.

Se alguém utilizar esse client (na versão que utilizo pelo menos) para trabalhar com o Sqlite vai se deparar com esta situação.